# C# static member gets null after init in Contructor

Tags: c#, static, bitmapimage

I have a class holding static ImageSource objects which are frequently accessed later on by other classes:

```
public class ImagePrepare
{
    public static readonly ImageSource m_imageGreen;
    public static readonly ImageSource m_imageYellow;
    public static readonly ImageSource m_imageRed;
    public static readonly ImageSource m_imagePurple;

    public static int iTest;

    //static Constructor
    static ImagePrepare()
    {
        iTest = 2;

        Uri uriImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Ressourcen/Button_Green.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource m_imageGreen = new BitmapImage(uriImage);

        uriImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Ressourcen/Button_Yellow.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource m_imageYellow = new BitmapImage(uriImage);

        uriImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Ressourcen/Button_Red.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource m_imageRed = new BitmapImage(uriImage);

        uriImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Ressourcen/Button_Purple.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource m_imagePurple = new BitmapImage(uriImage);
    }

    public static ImageSource GetImageSource()
    {
        return m_imageGreen;
    }
}
```

Now, when I call ImagePrepare.GetImageSource() from MainWindow class for example, first the static ctor is called and all static members are initialized correctly as supposed.
Then GetImageSource() gets called, but when in debug of this function the member m_imageGreen is null!
What am I missing here?
The member iTest behaves as supposed and still is holding its value of 2.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's a simple typo problem and so doesn't add to the SO knowledge base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your static constructor you overloaded your static members to be local.

By invoking:

```
ImageSource m_imageGreen = new BitmapImage(uriImage);
```

You in fact create a new local variable, instead of referring to the static one.
Do this:

```
m_imageGreen = new BitmapImage(uriImage);
```

Comment: I believe the correct term here is "hide" not "overload".